# How can I detect whether a template is an alias template?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

Given a "normal" template:

```
template<typename> struct Normal;
```

and an alias template:

```
template<typename>
using Alias = void;
```

**How can I, when given as template template parameter, differentiate between those two?**

So, ideally I want the following to compile:

```
int main() {
  static_assert(  is_alias_template<Alias>::value, "");
  static_assert(! is_alias_template<Normal>::value, "");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

One possible approach is to exploit that:

> Alias templates are never deduced by template argument deduction when deducing a template template parameter.
>
> http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Thus, with a type trait like

```
template<
  typename T,
  template<typename...> class Template
  >
struct instantiated_from
  : std::false_type {};

template<
  template<typename...> class Template,
  typename... Arguments
  >
struct instantiated_from<Template<Arguments...>, Template>
  : std::true_type {};
```

we can be sure that when we pass `Alias<int>` as first template parameter and `Alias` as second, then the compiler won't choose the specialization. This immediately gives us:

```
template<
  template<typename...> class Template,
  typename... Args
  >
struct is_alias_template
  : std::integral_constant<
      bool,
      ! instantiated_from<Template<Args...>, Template>::value
      >
{};
```

With this we can - *given some suitable template arguments* - detect whether a template is an alias template or not:

```
int main() {
    static_assert(  is_alias_template<Alias, int>::value, "");
    static_assert(! is_alias_template<Normal, int>::value, "");

    static_assert(  is_alias_template<Alias, Alias<int>>::value, "");
    static_assert(  is_alias_template<Alias, Normal<int>>::value, "");
    static_assert(! is_alias_template<Normal, Alias<int>>::value, "");
    static_assert(! is_alias_template<Normal, Normal<int>>::value, "");
}
```

The main drawback here is of course that one needs to know a set of suitable template arguments. Just guessing (or using `int`) won't work for example with templates with fixed number (>1) of template parameters.

Further this doesn't work with (alias or not) templates that have non-type (or template) template parameters.

Comment: If `template<class T> using Alias = Normal<T>` then this approach works with msvc and clang, but not gcc. Are there other possibilities that you know of?

Comment: @klaustriendl can you expand on that? Or better yet give an (complete but minimal) example where the above code won't work?

Comment: When the alias template has the same template parameters as the class template then gcc determines `instantiated_from<T>::value==true`. It needs to be different like in the OP's question `template<class T> using Alias = void`, or anything else like variadic template parameters `template<class... T> using Alias = Normal<T...>` or a dummy parameter `template<class T, class Dummy = void> using Aliase = Normal<T>`. See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Y8WsqsxP9).